# Convert guest customer to regular customer on successful order place in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento-2.1.7, guest-checkout

I'm looking for code to convert guest checkout customer to regular customer on successful order placement.

`\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderCustomerManagementInterface $orderCustomerService` in this class I have found one method called create that is accepting order id and converting to a customer. But I guess it is not working.

Anyone know the solution?

Comment: I found module of [Magento 2 Guest to Customer](https://www.mageants.com/guest-to-customer-for-magento-2.html) you can try this it will work

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I got the solution. By defining event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action and write a below code in observer we can convert the guest user to customer

```
        <?php
        $orderId = $orderIds[0];
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);

        /*Convert guest to customer*/
        if ($order->getEntityId() && $this->accountManagement->isEmailAvailable($order->getEmailAddress())) {
            $this->orderCustomerService->create($orderId);

        }
        /*END*/
        ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

> Use below event

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="guestregistration" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ConvertGuest" />
</event>
```

> In Observer file ConvertGuest.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class ConvertGuest implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderCustomerManagementInterface $orderCustomerService,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->orderCustomerService = $orderCustomerService;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

        $orderId = $orderIds[0];
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);

        $customer= $this->_customer->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());

        //Convert guest into customer
        if ($order->getId() && !$customer->getId()) {
            $this->orderCustomerService->create($orderId);
        } else {
            //if customer Registered and checkout as guest
            $order->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
            $order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
            $this->orderRepository->save($order);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :: if new customer not shown in customer-grid run `indexer:reindex` and check**

Comment: works perfectly but there is an extra comma to remove in you constructor after \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer(,)

Comment: any particular reason to use the OrderFactory? because load($orderId) is deprecated and there is already the OrderRepositoryInterface with get($orderId) to load the order.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the two extension links which does the same functionality - Second one is available as free package :

**Module Pay:** https://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-convert-guest-checkout-customers-to-registered-customers-magento-2.html

**Free Module on GitHub:** https://github.com/magepal/magento2-guest-to-customer

Comment: free module not working on magento 2.1.8

Comment: @LucasD.A.W. What issue are you having with the MagePal extension?

Comment: same on 2.1.9, blank page on Stores -> Configuration. composer require magepal/magento2-guest-to-customer | php bin/magento setup:upgrade (dev mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension :

- http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/customer-experience/convert-guest-to-user-for-magento-2.html
- https://magefan.com/magento2-convert-guest-to-customer
- https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-guest-to-customer-extension.html

Also, you can use code

```
$collection     = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
        $count          = 0;
        /** @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */

        foreach ($collection as $order) {
            $websiteId  = $order->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            $storeId    = $order->getStore()->getId();

            $customerData = $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
                    'order_address',
                    'to_customer',
                    $order->getBillingAddress(),
                    []
                    );



            $addresses = $order->getAddresses();
            foreach ($addresses as $address) {
                $addressData = $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
                        'order_address',
                        'to_customer_address',
                        $address,
                        []
                        );

                /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $customerAddress */
                $customerAddress = $this->addressFactory->create(['data' => $addressData]);
                switch ($address->getAddressType()) {
                    case QuoteAddress::ADDRESS_TYPE_BILLING:
                        $customerAddress->setIsDefaultBilling(true);
                        break;
                    case QuoteAddress::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING:
                        $customerAddress->setIsDefaultShipping(true);
                        break;
                }

                if (is_string($address->getRegion())) {
                    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface $region */
                    $region = $this->regionFactory->create();
                    $region->setRegion($address->getRegion());
                    $region->setRegionCode($address->getRegionCode());
                    $region->setRegionId($address->getRegionId());
                    $customerAddress->setRegion($region);
                }
                $customerData['addresses'][] = $customerAddress;
            }
            $account    = $this->createUser($customerData, $websiteId, $storeId, (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('group'), $count);

            $order
            ->setCustomerId($account->getId())
            ->setData('customer_group_id', $account->getGroupId())
            ->setData('customer_is_guest', 0)
            ->setData('customer_firstname', $account->getFirstname())
            ->setData('customer_lastname', $account->getLastname());

            $this->orderRepository->save($order);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guest Checkout

Your store can be configured to require shoppers to open an account before making a purchase. The default setting allows guests to make purchases, with an option to register for an account after they complete the checkout process.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-guest.html