# Magento 2 - Create customer programmatically from order

Tags: customer

What is most optimized way to create customer programmatically from order ?

As i need to create customer for a guest user, what will be the better way of implementing it ?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Details are already given, its simply asks how to create customer programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below reference code([Convert guest customer to regular customer on successful order place in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210997/convert-guest-customer-to-regular-customer-on-successful-order-place-in-magento/306438)). You can run that code by creating a custom script in the Magento root

```
 $collection     = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());

        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
        $count          = 0;
        /** @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */

        foreach ($collection as $order) {
            $websiteId  = $order->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            $storeId    = $order->getStore()->getId();

            $customerData = $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
                    'order_address',
                    'to_customer',
                    $order->getBillingAddress(),
                    []
                    );



            $addresses = $order->getAddresses();
            foreach ($addresses as $address) {
                $addressData = $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
                        'order_address',
                        'to_customer_address',
                        $address,
                        []
                        );

                /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $customerAddress */
                $customerAddress = $this->addressFactory->create(['data' => $addressData]);
                switch ($address->getAddressType()) {
                    case QuoteAddress::ADDRESS_TYPE_BILLING:
                        $customerAddress->setIsDefaultBilling(true);
                        break;
                    case QuoteAddress::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING:
                        $customerAddress->setIsDefaultShipping(true);
                        break;
                }

                if (is_string($address->getRegion())) {
                    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface $region */
                    $region = $this->regionFactory->create();
                    $region->setRegion($address->getRegion());
                    $region->setRegionCode($address->getRegionCode());
                    $region->setRegionId($address->getRegionId());
                    $customerAddress->setRegion($region);
                }
                $customerData['addresses'][] = $customerAddress;
            }
            $account    = $this->createUser($customerData, $websiteId, $storeId, (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('group'), $count);

            $order
            ->setCustomerId($account->getId())
            ->setData('customer_group_id', $account->getGroupId())
            ->setData('customer_is_guest', 0)
            ->setData('customer_firstname', $account->getFirstname())
            ->setData('customer_lastname', $account->getLastname());

            $this->orderRepository->save($order);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can we use "$this->orderCustomerService->create($orderId);" to convert guest to customer ?

Comment: I can see that magento uses "$this->orderCustomerService->create($orderId);" to convert guest to customer.

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal I just gave you the reference code, how to implement that is up to you. :) Please let me know if you need more details. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $loginHelper;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->loginHelper     = $helper;
    }

    public function install( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create( ['setup' => $setup] );
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_admin',
            [
                'type'         => 'int',
                'label'        => 'is_admin',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => false,
                'position'     => 999,
                'default'      => 0
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute( Customer::ENTITY, 'is_admin' );

        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']
        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();

        $configEmail = $this->loginHelper->getConfigEmail();
        $websiteId = ( int )$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
        $isEmailNotExists = $this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable( $configEmail, $websiteId );

        if ( $isEmailNotExists == true ) {
            $data = [
                'firstname' => 'admin',
                'lastname' => 'admin',
                'email' => $configEmail,
                'password'=>'abc123456',
                'is_admin'=>'1'
            ];

            $this->customerFactory->create()->setData( $data )->save();
        }
    }
}
```